# How to add a translated validation message to a form without entity with Symfony 2.3

Tags: symfony

I'm using **Symfony 2.3**. 
I have a simple contact form and I would like to add custom translated validation messages, like so (but I don't have an entity) :

```
class Author
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message = "author.name.not_blank")
     */
    public $name;
}
```

I have done :

```
namespace Me\MyBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;

class ContactType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
        ->add('name', 'text', array('constraints' => new NotBlank(array('message' => "contact.name.not_blank")),))
;
```

where in Me/MyBundle/Resources/translations, I have added in "validators.fr.yml" :

```
contact.name.not_blank: "Please enter a name."
```

The message that I get is "contact.name.not_blank",

Comment: Have you enabled the translator in the framework conf?

Comment: Have you cleared your cache?

Answer (score 0):

```
class ContactType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
        ->add('name', 'text', array('constraints' => 
             new NotBlank(array('message' => 
                $this->get('translator')->trans('contactname_notblank'))),
    ));
```

And the english translation yaml file:

```
// AppBundle/Resources/translations/messages.en.yml
contactname_notblank: The name field is required!
```